# How to clear screen in F# interactive in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#, f#-interactive

Is there any way to clear the F# interactive window in VS2010?

`#cls;;` and `#clear;;` don't work.

Quitting with `#quit;;` leads to the restart of F# interactive without clearing the window content.

Attempt to delete text with "delete" or "backspace" gives an error message that the text is read-only.

Comment: Is there any problem with Right mouse click -> `Clear All`?

Comment: @pad The only problem is that I didn't find it on my own. Strangely, I couldn't find it by decent googling either -- hence started a thread here.

Comment: The answer is that there is no directive in `fsi` to do so. But Visual Studio offers a context menu to help in this case. Alternatively, if you use `Reset Session` menu, F# Interactive console is also cleared.

Comment: @pad Actually it is a pity, because I use `fsi` for debugging and use verbose logging in my F# code -- it would be helpful to be able to delete the content programmatically from script. But I failed to find even the context menu trick while googling for this issue.

Comment: If you want to get rid of annoying declaration, this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971685/f-keep-f-interactive-from-posting-output could be helpful.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Clear All

. Right Click and Clear All.

Answer (score 12):

If you are inside of VS F# Interactive window, you can use right mouse click and select

```
Clear All
```

Unfortunately this will now work in stand alone console FSI window. So what you can do is to following command in your console FSI window

```
System.Console.Clear();;
```

Answer (score 3):

Would printing 30 newlines get what you want?  Just throwing out an idea.

Comment: That's actually not a bad idea Brian.  I mean I know what he's asking about and there are times when I'd like a "#clear;;" in FSI myself. :-)

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci: in fsi.exe, `System.Console.Clear();;` works.

Comment: In VS2012, System.Console.Clear() gives me this error: System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid.

Comment: @Brian LOL LOL - even though System.Console is prob the right choice, i will now always start my fsi with a function that does the 30 newlines - that's thinking outside the bun.. and then you can more easily ref your past methods if you decide to keep, so..... +1

Answer (score 1):

In VS 2022, you can simply press this, hopefully works on all versions

```
CTRL + ALT + C
```

Comment: This question is asking about VS 2010 not VS 2022

Comment: That is still a good answer, as many people (including me, who asked this question 10 years ago) have switched to VS 2022 :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, for the hint. I do rapid prototyping for compiled programs with f# and have the need as well quite often. Now that leads me to paste a function at the start of a session:

```
let cls = System.Console.Clear();;
```

Comment: didn't work as expected but; just for fun:
type blank()= member this.cls() = System.Console.Clear();;

invoke in fsi with blank().cls();;