# Suppress displaying content of variables in F# interactive

Tags: f#, f#-interactive, suppressmessage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [F# - Keep F# interactive from posting output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2971685/f-keep-f-interactive-from-posting-output)

Is there any way how to suppress displaying content of variables in F# interactive?

Why do I want it? This is what is printed out just for one call in F# interactive. To find any interesting information such as printfn in that is really a pain and that huge amount of data that is printed is useless for me anyways...

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.0.50727.1
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

For help type #help;;

> 

--> Referenced 'C:\Olda\Project_Root\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFit-2012\Solution\PostProcess\.\bin\Release\LBM.dll'


--> Referenced 'C:\Olda\Project_Root\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFit-2012\Solution\PostProcess\.\bin\Release\Utilities.dll'

find me

val dir : string = "2012-08-30-LOCylinder-NoFit-A"
val root : string =
  "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[65 chars]
val dirA : string [] =
  [|"y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[119 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[120 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[120 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[119 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[120 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[114 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[119 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[119 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[114 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[115 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[115 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[115 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[113 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[115 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[115 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[114 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[114 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[119 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[114 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[119 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[120 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[114 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[115 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[119 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[115 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[115 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[115 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[114 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[119 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[118 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[113 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[117 chars];
    "y:\Olda\Project\Computations\Oldrich\2012-Articles\07-FiberFi"+[116 chars];
    ...|]
val forceA : (float * float * float * float * float * float * float) [] =
  [|(0.000252805, 162180.0, 0.00554689, 0.00967337, 6.085089e-05, 4.16478e-10,
     4.166553e-10);
    (0.000487441, 47185.2, 0.020491, 0.0209057, 0.0005467281, 3.79865e-09,
     3.800069e-09);
    (0.000520718, 55692.3, 0.00697143, 0.00753794, 6.595801e-05, 1.432917e-09,
     1.432363e-09);
    (0.000550027, 96358.8, 0.00854397, 0.00240232, 2.442474e-05, 4.999992e-10,
     5.00477e-10);
    (0.000637991, 51724.8, 0.00528963, 0.0046053, 3.080306e-05, 1.337413e-09,
     1.33686e-09);
    (0.00066014, 43930.1, 0.0089495, 0.0114244, 0.0001314435, 3.54952e-09,
     3.548926e-09);
    (0.000663432, 40697.4, 0.020461, 0.0196952, 0.0005221612, 6.556135e-09,
     6.556114e-09);
    (0.000717394, 27878.7, 0.0139497, 0.000584649, 1.09966e-05, 2.270765e-10,
     2.270286e-10);
    (0.000724047, 71818.5, 0.0468557, 0.0094224, 0.0005404112, 3.747363e-09,
     3.748081e-09);
    (0.000749414, 42700.0, 0.0170848, 0.01729, 0.0003808691, 7.173521e-09,
     7.174374e-09);
    (0.000813187, 30743.3, 0.0623997, 0.06458, 0.005377043, 3.260309e-08,
     3.260849e-08);
    (0.000833705, 53975.9, 0.0611242, 0.0626591, 0.004822256, 3.280713e-08,
     3.280833e-08);
    (0.000885524, 40653.9, 0.0211935, 0.0211017, 0.0005795428, 1.203752e-08,
     1.203399e-08);
    (0.000886704, 24811.0, 0.0575155, 0.0426739, 0.00335128, 2.626019e-08,
     2.621327e-08);
    (0.000892993, 39194.0, 0.0537971, 0.0465439, 0.003257076, 2.806999e-08,
     2.807582e-08);
    (0.000919246, 40250.4, 0.0117258, 0.00157283, 2.392413e-05, 9.683138e-10,
     9.683923e-10);
    (0.0009245, 28123.3, 0.0777698, 0.00908261, 0.0009515064, 5.969178e-09,
     5.970366e-09);
    (0.000930961, 21483.2, 0.0339286, 0.0246477, 0.001159995, 1.643661e-08,
     1.643989e-08);
    (0.000933435, 56779.6, 0.0810023, 0.0373661, 0.003791664, 2.443185e-08,
     2.443248e-08);
    (0.00093525, 40630.8, 0.0399094, 0.0178482, 0.0009231236, 1.190616e-08,
     1.190947e-08);
    (0.000943539, 23316.5, 0.067747, 0.0591666, 0.005510258, 4.073487e-08,
     4.074218e-08);
    (0.000952661, 32540.4, 0.0588305, 0.0322833, 0.002519025, 2.246114e-08,
     2.246379e-08);
    (0.000955299, 45012.1, 0.0706107, 0.0434361, 0.003933234, 3.033197e-08,
     3.033881e-08);
    (0.000957235, 25072.2, 0.0712521, 0.0462312, 0.004492653, 3.275724e-08,
     3.276463e-08);
    (0.000996275, 51190.7, 0.0162435, 0.00258837, 5.32194e-05, 1.834346e-09,
     1.833968e-09);
    (0.00100803, 48609.6, 0.0351237, 0.0111806, 0.0004996876, 8.370027e-09,
     8.367669e-09);
    (0.00102104, 49948.9, 0.085035, 0.03227, 0.00348206, 2.470744e-08,
     2.471084e-08);
    (0.00103962, 36551.9, 0.048354, 0.0223518, 0.001416119, 1.854891e-08,
     1.854854e-08);
    (0.0010463, 24849.4, 0.105262, 0.0834671, 0.01199443, 7.070312e-08,
     7.069647e-08);
    (0.00105721, 33105.9, 0.0402657, 0.02732, 0.001456394, 2.33656e-08,
     2.335479e-08);
    (0.00107435, 37231.9, 0.0963023, 0.0845338, 0.01064605, 7.474111e-08,
     7.472305e-08);
    (0.00107624, 25087.2, 0.0952104, 0.0608672, 0.007903313, 5.438275e-08,
     5.437514e-08);
    (0.00109594, 47447.9, 0.0407242, 0.0326682, 0.001696979, 2.977274e-08,
     2.977017e-08);
    (0.00110379, 53452.1, 0.0593868, 0.0276272, 0.00206778, 2.536138e-08,
     2.534933e-08);
    (0.00115744, 43198.7, 0.024398, 0.00429235, 0.0001348665, 4.195718e-09,
     4.195235e-09);
    (0.00117978, 16952.3, 0.12626, 0.0301736, 0.005426417, 3.282684e-08,
     3.278765e-08);
    (0.00120028, 34158.6, 0.0325227, 0.00597382, 0.000256372, 6.536934e-09,
     6.53295e-09);
    (0.00122926, 17896.9, 0.124676, 0.0847117, 0.01495147, 9.904861e-08,
     9.905314e-08);
    (0.00123643, 36395.1, 0.111293, 0.0408434, 0.005958529, 4.817523e-08,
     4.816387e-08);
    (0.00124992, 43202.6, 0.0590766, 0.0121188, 0.0009219895, 1.423823e-08,
     1.423623e-08);
    (0.001272, 28302.0, 0.0949724, 0.0396994, 0.00507548, 4.948594e-08,
     4.94959e-08);
    (0.0012874, 25633.1, 0.137221, 0.0407709, 0.007611981, 5.206046e-08,
     5.206579e-08);
    (0.00131784, 25041.0, 0.0272075, 0.0174181, 0.0006464227, 2.316323e-08,
     2.31496e-08);
    (0.00135293, 24391.6, 0.175938, 0.0698772, 0.01681764, 1.002225e-07,
     1.000757e-07);
    (0.00138081, 24623.2, 0.0219953, 0.00237801, 7.147705e-05, 3.421686e-09,
     3.42296e-09);
    (0.00138722, 18742.6, 0.147133, 0.0717624, 0.01487001, 1.06958e-07,
     1.069541e-07);
    (0.00139011, 28055.4, 0.175219, 0.0799703, 0.01888046, 1.198027e-07,
     1.198163e-07);
    (0.00141441, 40299.4, 0.140834, 0.0120105, 0.002193942, 1.851482e-08,
     1.852465e-08);
    (0.00144188, 27048.0, 0.096203, 0.0158642, 0.002064509, 2.546946e-08,
     2.547052e-08);
    (0.00145794, 20576.9, 0.0298659, 0.0142573, 0.0005934664, 2.238276e-08,
     2.238653e-08);
    (0.0014588, 26048.8, 0.0189348, 0.00905385, 0.0002328446, 1.403915e-08,
     1.403417e-08);
    (0.00148458, 35026.7, 0.0502257, 0.00209144, 0.0001382484, 3.497224e-09,
     3.495815e-09);
    (0.00150793, 18568.6, 0.0791763, 0.0471974, 0.005268336, 8.268661e-08,
     8.270279e-08);
    (0.00151242, 25125.2, 0.124505, 0.0408327, 0.006932091, 6.975898e-08,
     6.97626e-08);
    (0.00152236, 24961.2, 0.122531, 0.0467549, 0.007817189, 8.385714e-08,
     8.385767e-08);
    (0.001547, 35552.7, 0.193467, 0.0608618, 0.01547265, 1.127605e-07,
     1.127148e-07);
    (0.00155408, 23808.3, 0.0155603, 0.000334059, 7.129467e-06, 5.90586e-10,
     5.908897e-10);
    (0.00158524, 30279.3, 0.016816, 0.00528343, 0.0001187417, 9.645225e-09,
     9.645381e-09);
    (0.00162094, 34547.9, 0.184929, 0.0360896, 0.008796386, 7.280724e-08,
     7.282266e-08);
    (0.00162749, 25806.6, 0.0699643, 0.036791, 0.003499689, 7.512538e-08,
     7.513471e-08);
    (0.00163032, 14721.0, 0.165242, 0.0809329, 0.01935831, 1.664562e-07,
     1.664348e-07);
    (0.00164021, 13412.9, 0.00929598, 0.00208771, 2.839679e-05, 4.228591e-09,
     4.226611e-09);
    (0.00167718, 28619.5, 0.162502, 0.0477672, 0.01043674, 1.036319e-07,
     1.036323e-07);
    (0.00168363, 14848.9, 0.00564324, 0.000503082, 4.10542e-06, 1.038905e-09,
     1.039067e-09);
    (0.0016948, 15341.0, 0.0683535, 0.0254706, 0.002508205, 5.644664e-08,
     5.644154e-08);
    (0.00170297, 19965.1, 0.109147, 0.0558788, 0.008529023, 1.251625e-07,
     1.251524e-07);
    (0.00171787, 11642.4, 0.198148, 0.0104563, 0.003082397, 2.408784e-08,
     2.40608e-08);
    (0.00175362, 25091.0, 0.0272078, 0.0116939, 0.0004338976, 2.595698e-08,
     2.596283e-08);
    (0.00179906, 22233.8, 0.167863, 0.0785212, 0.01821428, 1.965587e-07,
     1.965953e-07);
    (0.00182353, 25225.8, 0.139036, 0.0518671, 0.009828804, 1.322449e-07,
     1.322379e-07);
    (0.00182541, 25199.9, 0.0174015, 0.000704463, 1.670998e-05, 1.688746e-09,
     1.689449e-09);
    (0.00182739, 15322.4, 0.113769, 0.0241431, 0.003957699, 6.249733e-08,
     6.250108e-08);
    (0.00185073, 28096.9, 0.0903243, 0.0460074, 0.005598434, 1.207809e-07,
     1.207781e-07);
    (0.00186179, 10742.3, 0.157882, 0.0223946, 0.005310731, 6.064575e-08,
     6.057653e-08);
    (0.00188412, 20168.5, 0.0542341, 0.0132197, 0.001001485, 3.550366e-08,
     3.550389e-08);
    (0.00191558, 14617.0, 0.0220315, 0.00631808, 0.0002016541, 1.763334e-08,
     1.762716e-08);
    (0.00202938, 17246.7, 0.191014, 0.0885049, 0.0240329, 2.826085e-07,
     2.825911e-07);
    (0.00206499, 27118.7, 0.121295, 0.0559185, 0.009172486, 1.668244e-07,
     1.668091e-07);
    (0.00206619, 27587.0, 0.101336, 0.00927483, 0.001268692, 3.027083e-08,
     3.026967e-08);
    (0.00207698, 22629.1, 0.0423963, 0.0178522, 0.001043879, 5.87145e-08,
     5.87333e-08);
    (0.00207977, 24521.9, 0.0333769, 0.010852, 0.0004951917, 3.537309e-08,
     3.537789e-08);
    (0.00208279, 22565.8, 0.195274, 0.0878693, 0.02367255, 2.949477e-07,
     2.950273e-07);
    (0.00210202, 25689.6, 0.150102, 0.0466212, 0.009519103, 1.586041e-07,
     1.585692e-07);
    (0.00213353, 18279.6, 0.110481, 0.0460817, 0.007190182, 1.61821e-07,
     1.618236e-07);
    (0.00215991, 19908.2, 0.106019, 0.027996, 0.004151994, 1.010028e-07,
     1.010277e-07);
    (0.0021624, 13411.0, 0.0101879, 0.00156348, 2.330703e-05, 5.403599e-09,
     5.40351e-09);
    (0.00219896, 18645.2, 0.153803, 0.00326262, 0.0007071175, 1.220963e-08,
     1.221263e-08);
    (0.00220626, 22662.8, 0.0791613, 0.0330102, 0.003603459, 1.235708e-07,
     1.236013e-07);
    (0.00224368, 22730.5, 0.192637, 0.0716969, 0.01903954, 2.768049e-07,
     2.768512e-07);
    (0.0022585, 8855.45, 0.0679218, 0.0132517, 0.001383893, 5.18928e-08,
     5.189262e-08);
    (0.00226939, 10575.5, 0.0633549, 0.0232409, 0.002215771, 9.245644e-08,
     9.245358e-08);
    (0.00231805, 17255.8, 0.163242, 0.0533493, 0.01237959, 2.216643e-07,
     2.216143e-07);
    (0.00238805, 10468.8, 0.111566, 0.00765519, 0.001286787, 3.381924e-08,
     3.382155e-08);
    (0.00244194, 20885.0, 0.130118, 0.0232523, 0.004209901, 1.072081e-07,
     1.071693e-07);
    (0.00245371, 23637.7, 0.00999943, 0.00266996, 3.664683e-05, 1.152522e-08,
     1.15296e-08);
    (0.00248078, 13705.4, 0.0354435, 0.00302761, 0.0001566213, 1.391716e-08,
     1.39188e-08);
    (0.00249976, 10401.0, 0.0101375, 0.00374399, 5.723007e-05, 1.763545e-08,
     1.763765e-08);
    (0.00251419, 12330.0, 0.14032, 0.0540821, 0.01121383, 2.678675e-07,
     2.67433e-07);
    (0.00253126, 14617.2, 0.0790567, 0.0242715, 0.002779797, 1.1964e-07,
     1.196354e-07);
    (0.00253237, 19349.4, 0.149013, 0.0299842, 0.006270092, 1.381995e-07,
     1.381904e-07); ...|]
val forceA2 : (float * float) [] =
  [|(1.152183801e-05, 6.847152112e-06); (1.159527248e-05, 6.950564641e-06);
    (3.88940627e-05, 2.171628586e-05); (3.540856308e-05, 2.049057636e-05);
    (7.694914693e-05, 4.340023361e-05); (4.869376162e-05, 2.699963102e-05);
    (2.151126624e-05, 1.2555728e-05); (3.689356411e-05, 2.064534492e-05);
    (1.118847991e-05, 6.935609403e-06); (3.287257348e-05, 1.883684972e-05);
    (1.059737622e-05, 6.064390781e-06); (1.137133945e-05, 6.803523081e-06);
    (3.699968172e-05, 2.076462687e-05); (1.367012342e-05, 7.821868062e-06);
    (1.482303875e-05, 8.619946234e-06); (7.206443983e-05, 4.04776391e-05);
    (1.099013049e-05, 6.274646182e-06); (2.554447821e-05, 1.417238005e-05);
    (1.075649579e-05, 6.443735521e-06); (2.191695597e-05, 1.290127346e-05);
    (1.314103716e-05, 7.393878835e-06); (1.542674261e-05, 8.917652663e-06);
    (1.292433271e-05, 7.713451577e-06); (1.285995564e-05, 7.292935822e-06);
    (6.1105296e-05, 3.446051628e-05); (2.892988156e-05, 1.674580078e-05);
    (1.225992452e-05, 7.096615222e-06); (2.23520235e-05, 1.309815065e-05);
    (1.040017946e-05, 5.894108349e-06); (2.775794247e-05, 1.603603832e-05);
    (1.198546579e-05, 7.018852063e-06); (1.21656094e-05, 6.88004385e-06);
    (2.949313881e-05, 1.754303972e-05); (2.051554157e-05, 1.225920069e-05);
    (5.490890047e-05, 3.110657576e-05); (1.102392562e-05, 6.042228233e-06);
    (4.429743159e-05, 2.548230696e-05); (1.212005637e-05, 6.624976675e-06);
    (1.373634591e-05, 8.083181268e-06); (2.644532702e-05, 1.544077237e-05);
    (1.703636004e-05, 9.751964346e-06); (1.207831717e-05, 6.839978975e-06);
    (6.383174733e-05, 3.581186119e-05); (1.040377624e-05, 5.950638734e-06);
    (8.668380318e-05, 4.788893778e-05); (1.307918229e-05, 7.192604443e-06);
    (1.102851752e-05, 6.346047713e-06); (1.420506162e-05, 8.44354591e-06);
    (2.161073911e-05, 1.233732573e-05); (7.117110295e-05, 3.772164692e-05);
    (0.0001123908063, 6.027268831e-05); (4.388147455e-05, 2.528647709e-05);
    (2.87188576e-05, 1.56980857e-05); (1.837206744e-05, 1.006371671e-05);
    (1.89142337e-05, 1.072734329e-05); (1.23701148e-05, 7.284776687e-06);
    (0.0001552132444, 8.287992637e-05); (0.0001494401676, 8.12299386e-05);
    (1.420786617e-05, 8.278702185e-06); (3.785821769e-05, 2.146896767e-05);
    (1.608515573e-05, 8.597589356e-06); (0.0002894034673, 0.0001488411542);
    (1.731014235e-05, 9.929566129e-06); (0.000502301865, 0.0002530963945);
    (4.202194533e-05, 2.250276194e-05); (2.657065078e-05, 1.467370882e-05);
    (1.489329863e-05, 7.805873157e-06); (0.0001130257906, 5.9836307e-05);
    (1.928130013e-05, 1.079347084e-05); (2.391655155e-05, 1.345411914e-05);
    (0.000191484738, 0.0001011041904); (2.935205735e-05, 1.579227728e-05);
    (3.792115226e-05, 2.157355075e-05); (2.195476371e-05, 1.140643915e-05);
    (6.545527951e-05, 3.54512449e-05); (0.0001665545576, 8.741285201e-05);
    (2.156063526e-05, 1.175851021e-05); (3.515547797e-05, 1.818581135e-05);
    (4.212857342e-05, 2.385895868e-05); (0.0001017505282, 5.626447127e-05);
    (0.0001295939183, 7.144281699e-05); (2.221501165e-05, 1.24628441e-05);
    (2.943657033e-05, 1.665799813e-05); (4.120120438e-05, 2.250618969e-05);
    (4.400353906e-05, 2.433233285e-05); (0.0004589732683, 0.0002318403503);
    (3.143908169e-05, 1.727100517e-05); (6.148942965e-05, 3.430073715e-05);
    (2.613257029e-05, 1.45408555e-05); (7.509845514e-05, 3.749756665e-05);
    (8.129017601e-05, 4.172524146e-05); (3.291650312e-05, 1.79015864e-05);
    (5.111577723e-05, 2.628372062e-05); (4.582817876e-05, 2.545648936e-05);
    (0.0006021035963, 0.0003146138425); (0.000173636052, 8.886913849e-05);
    (0.0006164044446, 0.00030818851); (4.5048114e-05, 2.384849779e-05);
    (8.104660563e-05, 4.303745921e-05); (4.303582786e-05, 2.203961282e-05);
    ...|]
val text : string =
  "1.15218e-05  6.84715e-06
1.15953e-05 6.95056e-06
3.88941e-05 2"+[18658 chars]
val it : unit = ()

>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5321031/162396

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can turn off printing declaration values in F# Interactive but still keep type information:

```
fsi.ShowDeclarationValues <- false
```

The advantage is that you can toggle the option on and off in the same `fsi` session.

You may be interested in other [properties of an interactive session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/fsharp-interactive-options#f-interactive-structured-printing).

Answer (score 3):

Start fsi with the `--quiet` option - then it won't print out values.

From `fsi --help`

> ```
> --quiet                        Suppress fsi writing to stdout
> ```

Comment: If you're using VS, you can set this option in Tools/Options.../F# Tools/F# Interactive.

Comment: A little bit too aggressive as it does not display anything (not even type information etc.) but at least something. Thank you for that hint ;)